# How to get AWS EMR cluster id and step id from inside the spark application step submitted

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, apache-spark, amazon-emr

Scenario:
I am running the Spark Scala job in AWS EMR. Now my job dumps some metadata unique to that application. Now for dumping I am writing at location "s3://bucket/key/<APPLICATION_ID>" Where ApplicationId is  `val APPLICATION_ID: String = getSparkSession.sparkContext.getConf.getAppId`

Now basically is there a way to write at s3 location something like "s3://bucket/key/<emr_cluster_id>_<emr_step_id>".
How can i get the cluster id and step id from inside the spark Scala application.

Writing in this way will help me debug and help me in reaching the cluster based and debug the logs.

Is there any way other than reading the "/mnt/var/lib/info/job-flow.json"  ?

PS: I am new to spark, scala and emr . Apologies in advance if this is an obvious query.

Answer (score 4):

With PySpark on EMR, `EMR_CLUSTER_ID` and `EMR_STEP_ID` are available as environment variables (confirmed on emr-5.30.1).

They can be used in code as follows:

```
import os
emr_cluster_id = os.environ.get('EMR_CLUSTER_ID')
emr_step_id = os.environ.get('EMR_STEP_ID')
```

I can't test but the following similar code should work in Scala.

```
val emr_cluster_id = sys.env.get("EMR_CLUSTER_ID")
val emr_step_id = sys.env.get("EMR_STEP_ID")
```

Since `sys.env` is simply a `Map[String, String]` its `get` method returns an `Option[String]`, which doesn't fail if these environment variables don't exist. If you want to raise an Exception you could use `sys.env("EMR_x_ID")`

The `EMR_CLUSTER_ID` and `EMR_STEP_ID` variables are visible in the Spark History Server UI under the Environment tab, alongside with other variables that may be of interest.

*(Update 2023-03-02: It seems these variables are not visible on the Spark History Server UI, at least for EMR 6.7+, but are still available as environment variables in code.)*

Comment: From EMR 6.7.0 seems these variables don't appear anymore.. any other solution?

Comment: I agree on EMR 6.9 this only works when deploy-mode=client

Comment: It still works for me on EMR 6.7.0, when I SSH to the master node and run `pyspark` or `spark-shell` interactively. However, I did notice that the variables don't appear on the Spark History server UI anymore. Can you confirm the same?

Answer (score 1):

I was having same problem recenlty to get the cluster-id programitically. I ended by using [listClusters()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/elasticmapreduce/AmazonElasticMapReduceClient.html#listClusters--) method of the emrClient.

You can use Java SDK for AWS or [Scala wrapper](https://github.com/seratch/AWScala) on top of it to use this method.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on top of [A.B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3680831/a-b)'s answer, you can pass the cluster ID to [listSteps](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/emr/EmrClient.html#listSteps-java.util.function.Consumer-) method to get a list of the step IDs like this:

```
emrClient.listSteps(new ListStepsRequest().withClusterId(jobFlowId)).getSteps()
```